# Metal teeth and 1901

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

What has teeth,
But is not alive,
It could bite you,
But it doesn’t try,

It is made of metal,
But used to seal things,
Made by Gideon,
In 1901.

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It's the zipper invented by Gideon Sundback

What has teeth,

> It sure does

But is not alive,

> No, it's not

It could bite you,

> If you are not careful (ouch)

But it doesn’t try,

> No, it doesn't.

It is made of metal,

> Among other materials

But used to seal things,

> That's the whole idea - seal together things

Made by Gideon,
In 1901.

> Invented by Gideon Sundback in 1901

The inventors name was correct, thanks to @PaulKaram.

Comment: your answer fits better than mine, nice one..

Comment: Yesss! You did it!

Comment: rot13('Znqr ol Tvqrba, / Va [...].') spoiled it, eh? :P

Comment: His last name is **Sundback**, not Sunback ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think it is-

> A Stapler. Its not alive, but has metal teeth that is used to seal and join papers. Also the first published use of the word "stapler" to indicate a machine for fastening papers with a thin metal wire was in an advertisement in the American Munsey's Magazine in 1901

Comment: Unfortunately not the right answer